# OneNote Layout formatting

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Is there any way to format a OneNote Page or do I have to manually move each item? I have several items on a page overlapping each other in Several notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in tools for the task. But still you can use **Insert Space** tool to correct overlaying issues with lesser effort.

[image]

Steps:

1. Temporarily move few overlapping block(s) (let's call them "OB's") up or down so the page can get cut into top and bottom part by single horizontal line which is not intersecting any blocks (because they were moved).
2. Using **Insert Space** tool, click where the virtual line runs and by dragging the mouse down insert enough space for OB's.
3. Move OB's to newly created space.

Compared to selecting and moving blocks individually, the above approach is relatively fast and convenient because it moves all blocks below the line at once.

*If anything was unclear, let me know and I can add images.*